# how to export a variable values from TRACE32

Tags: debugging, embedded, trace32, lauterbach

My question is how to export a variable value which I have seen in watch window?  I need to append the values of that variable in Excel format, I'm using the TRACE32 software.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can export variables to a CSV file as displayed in the Var.WATCH window with command `Var.EXPORT`. Each variable will get its own line in the CSV. To ensure that only the data and not also the command Var.EXPORT gets part of the result use the command `WinPOS ,,,,,0` before `Var.EXPORT`.

E.g. to export the scalar variables x and y to a CSV file including the type information you can use the commands:

```
WinPOS ,,,,,0
Var.EXPORT myfile.csv %Hex %Type x y
```

Comment: https://www2.lauterbach.com/pdf/general_ref_v.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You can write / append to a file using OPEN, WRITE and CLOSE. Every Spreadsheet program can read CSV and it's easy to write:

```
OPEN #1 <file name> /Create
WRITE #1 "," Var.VALUE(<variable name>)
CLOSE #1
```

Writing to a Microsoft Excel file, e.g. XLSX is much more complicated, there are libraries for this in other languages, but I don't think there's anything in TRACE32.

If you want to write it manually you can look into adding a custom button (MENU.AddTool), otherwise you'll need to specify your condition(s).